# Is this consider hardcoding in Powerapps canvas-app functions?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Below is what I have written, may I know if the canvas-app functions are considered hardcoded... :

```
If(
    "EC - Empire Complex" in BuildingDropdown.Selected.Value &&
        "Storey 1" in StoreyDropdown.Selected.Value &&
        "Office" in AreaNameDropdown.Selected.Value,
    Distinct(
        Filter(
            Area,
            "1" in buildingID,
            "Storey 1" in storey_x0020_,
            "Office" in areaName_x0020_),
        areaDescription_x0020_)))
```

Comment: Please enter the the expression as a text, and not as an image. If you have it as text here, the community should be able to copy/paste and look at it easier.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I have already updated! Please help me take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first edit that you had (where you had the entire expression, not only the simplified version), this can definitely be improved. To answer the main question - yes, the expression is hard-coding the values in the `in` expressions where it doesn't need to.

For example, look at the beginning of this expression:

```
If(
    "EC - Empire Complex" in BuildingDropdown.Selected.Value &&
        "Storey 1" in StoreyDropdown.Selected.Value &&
        "Office" in AreaNameDropdown.Selected.Value,
    Distinct(
        Filter(
            Area,
            "1" in buildingID,
            "Storey 1" in storey_x0020_,
            "Office" in areaName_x0020_),
        areaDescription_x0020_),
    If(
        "EC - Empire Complex" in BuildingDropdown.Selected.Value &&
            "Storey 1" in StoreyDropdown.Selected.Value &&
            "Meeting rooms" in AreaNameDropdown.Selected.Value,
        Distinct(
            Filter(
                Area,
                "1" in buildingID,
                "Storey 1" in storey_x0020_,
                "Meeting rooms" in areaName_x0020_),
            areaDescription_x0020_),
        If(
            "EC - Empire Complex" in BuildingDropdown.Selected.Value &&
                "Storey 1" in StoreyDropdown.Selected.Value &&
                "Pantry" in AreaNameDropdown.Selected.Value,
            Distinct(
                Filter(
                    Area,
                    "1" in buildingID,
                    "Storey 1" in storey_x0020_,
                    "Pantry" in areaName_x0020_),
                areaDescription_x0020_),
            // And many more lines
```

The expressions in the [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) statements seem to come directly from the conditions in the [`If`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if) clause, so they can be used directly in them:

```
If(
    "EC - Empire Complex" in BuildingDropdown.Selected.Value,
    Distinct(
        Filter(
            Area,
            "1" in buildingID,
            StoreyDropdown.Selected.Value in storey_x0020_,
            AreaNameDropdown.Selected.Value in areaName_x0020_),
        areaDescription_x0020_))
```